# matrix multiplication isn't working

Tags: r, shiny

I'm having trouble with matrix multiplication. LMatrix has the dimensions 381 by 381, and directEffects1 has the dimensions 381x 1.Both are data frames. When I type up

```
  writeData(wb2, sheet=1, as.matrix(LMatrix)%*%as.matrix(directEffects1)[,1], startCol = 9,startRow = 1,colNames = T, rowNames = FALSE)
```

I get a 1 row, 381 column vector with just 1s and 0s, and not the products of the matrix multiplication. Also, I need to write as.matrix(directEffects1)[,1] and not as.matrix(directEffects1), or else I will receive the message:

```
 %*%: non-conformable arguments
```

Any advice on what I should do? I want the 381x1 product of the two variables.

Comment: It would be great if you could make a reproducible example. When I multiply matrices in R, it works just fine. But I can't multiply your matrices unless you share them. Do you still see the problem if you get rid of  the `writeData()` function call? It doesn't seem related to your question. What if you just multiply `LMatrix[1:4,1:4]` by `directEffects1[1:4, 1]`? If that still shows the problem, then you could share those subsets of the objects with us (using `dput()` so they are copy-pasteable) and we could try to help.

Comment: Also share the class and dimensions of `directEffects1`, since that seems to be a problem. Maybe `str(LMatrix)` and `str(directEffects)` so we know what is really there.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you're going wrong. I worked up an example using randomly generated data and got a sensible answer:

```
library(openxlsx)
library(Matrix)

# Using rnorm and runif to generate random data
LMatrix = as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(381*381), nrow=381, ncol=381))
directEffects1 = as.data.frame(matrix(runif(381), nrow=381, ncol=1))
wb2 <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb2, "Matrix")

writeData(wb2, sheet=1, 
          as.matrix(LMatrix)%*%as.matrix(directEffects1)[,1], 
          startCol = 9,
          startRow = 1,
          colNames = T, 
          rowNames = FALSE)

saveWorkbook(wb2, file = 'C:/test.xlsx')
```

Which gives a 381 row x 1 column Excel file. Perhaps this code (which isn't really an answer, admittedly) can get you started figuring out what part of your code or data is messing you up?